# How to Call Perl script from tcl script

Tags: perl, tcl

I have a file with 4 perl commands ,
I want to  open the file  from the tcl and  execute each perl command.

**TCL script**

```
runcmds $file

proc runcmds {file} {

    set fileid [open $file "r"]
    set options [read $fileid]
    close $fileid

    set options [split $options "\n"]    #saperating each commad  with new line

    foreach line $options {
    exec perl $line  
    }
}
```

when executing the above script 
I am getting the  error as  `"can't open the perl  script /../../    :   No Such file or directory " Use -S to search $PATH for it`.

Comment: Overall, it looks good to me. If I were you I would try with full paths for everything: both the perl binary, as well as anything that may come in the $options variable.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr:** You were missing `-e`, causing your script to be interpreted as a filename.

---

To run a perl command from inside Tcl:

```
proc perl {script args} {
    exec perl -e $script {*}$args
    # or in 8.4: eval [list perl -e $script] $args
}
```

Then you can do:

```
puts [perl {
    print "Hello "
    print "World\n"
}]
```

That's right, an arbitrary perl script inside Tcl. You can even pass in other arguments as necessary; access from perl via `@ARGV`. (You'll need to add other options like `-p` explicitly.)

Note that this can pass whole scripts; you don't need to split them up (and probably shouldn't; you *can* do lots with one-liners but they tend to be awful to maintain and there's no technical reason to require it).

Comment: Hi Donal thaks for the info,

Can you give some more info ,
how to write if the $line is a perl file