# tcl script to run perl code and output the results?

Tags: tcl

I need to run perl script through tcl script, but exec command in tcl is not generating the results of perl script.

tcl script (test.tcl) has following line

```
exec perl test.pl
```

perl script test.pl has following lines.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
print "Have a nice day!!!";
```

I am running tcl through cmd window as "tclsh test.tcl". No errors and no output. Why it is so???

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103586/how-to-call-perl-script-from-tcl-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec` command will return the output of the program and you have to capture it by saving it into a variable, or straightaway print it using `puts`.

```
set result [exec perl test.pl]
puts $result
```

Comment: However this code is not working when perl script generates a output file. Hence i used "exec perl test.pl" alone as code, but output file is not generated.

Comment: @SumathiGokul that sounds like quite a different question. Please ask a new one.